# Why do I have a 'memory allocation error' with the following code?

Tags: memory-management, erlang, heap-memory

I've written the below code to do some playing around with roundoff error. If I call loopUp with values higher than 7, I get a memory allocation error which I don't know how to fix. I've tried 32/64 bit Erlang on Windows 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-module(roundOff).
-export([main/0]).

main() ->
    loopUp(10).

loopUp(1) -> 1;
loopUp(I) -> 
    io:fwrite("~f ", [math:pow(10.0, I)]),
    sumUp(seq_float(1.0, math:pow(10, I), 1.0)),
    loopUp(I-1).

sumUp(L) ->
    sumUp(L, 0).

sumUp([], Acc) ->
    io:fwrite("~.20f~n", [Acc]),
    Acc;

sumUp([H|T], Acc) ->
    sumUp(T, Acc+1.0/H).

seq_float(Min, Max, Inc, Counter, Acc) when (Counter*Inc + Min) >= Max -> 
    lists:reverse([Max|Acc]);

seq_float(Min, Max, Inc, Counter, Acc) -> 
    seq_float(Min, Max, Inc, Counter+1, [Inc * Counter + Min|Acc]).

seq_float(Min, Max, Inc) -> 
    seq_float(Min, Max, Inc, 0, []).
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you are generating in seq_float is way too long.  Rather than generate all of the numbers in advance, try calculating each one as you need it.